# How do I create list and detail views for django-taggit?

Tags: django, django-views, django-taggit

I have a fairly simple model that uses Django Taggit for tagging.

Everything works great, but now I'd like to expand some functionality and I'm a little confused.

What I want is two views.

One that shows all my tags in the system.
One that shows all the content from my app with a specific tag.

What makes sense to me is to do the following for each view.

in views.py for myapp

1. All Tags

   from myapp.models import App

   from taggit.models import Tag

   class TagList(ListView):

   """ Get all the tags in the db """

   ```
   queryset = Tag.objects.all()
   template_name = "myapp/TagList.html"
   paginate_by = 10
   ```
2. All content for a Tag

   from myapp.models import App

   from taggit.models import Tag

   class TaggedList(ListView):
       """ Get all the contet for a tag """

   ```
   template_name = "myapp/TaggedList.html"

   def get_object(self):
       return get_list_or_404(App, tag__iexact=self.kwargs['tag'])
   ```

Have I lost my mind or is it really that easy? BTW, I'm using generic class views.

Thanks for the help.
Dave

Comment: ok, so the first one works great, and that is how I can do that.

Comment: The second one isn't work. I'm getting an integer error which tells me that I'm asking for the wrong thing.

Comment: return get_list_or_404(App, tags=self.kwargs['tag']) - that's the query I'm using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.
I believe this is for returning a single object, not multiple objects.

```
def get_object(self):
```

Instead perhaps you should try something like the following:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return TaggedItem.objects.filter(tag__iexact=self.kwargs['tag'])
```

This returns a list of items with GenericForeignKeys

If you are only interested in a specific model called App then

```
    return App.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[self.kwargs['tag']])
```

Default variable name in the template is TaggedItem_list then

```
{% for item in TaggedItem_list %}
   {{item.content_object}} {# generic foreign key here #}
{% endfor %}
```

The urls.py would have to be similar to

```
url(r'someapp/(?P<tag>\w+)/$', TaggedList.as_view())
```