# Return a list of objects from selected tags

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I am trying to figure out what I thought would be easy to find an answer for. I am using django-taggit in  a project and I simply want to return a list of objects when a tag is selected. I have tried this:

[How do I create list and detail views for django-taggit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314979/how-do-i-create-list-and-detail-views-for-django-taggit/8426729#8426729)

But I cannot get it to work. It just renders a blank page. I think the problem is in my template code. Maybe someone can point me in the direction. Any help would be appreciated..Thanks a lot.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField 
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase

class Tagged(TaggedItemBase):
content_object = models.ForeignKey('Shows')

class Shows(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
tags = TaggableManager(through=Tagged)
hosts = models.ManyToManyField('Host', blank=True, null=True)
featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
thumbnail = FilerImageField(related_name="thumbnail", help_text="Image should be: 550 X 350.")
playing_next = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
description = RichTextField()
```

views.py:

```
class TaggedList(ListView):
queryset = Shows.objects.all()
paginate_by = 10
template_name = "tagged.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    return Shows.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[self.kwargs['tag']])
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('radio.views',
                   url(r'^$', 'main', name='app_main'),
                   url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/detail/$', 'detail_view', name='detailsview'),
                   url(r'^(?P<tag>\w+)/$', TaggedList.as_view()),
                   url(r'^tagged/(?P<tag>\w+)/$', TaggedList.as_view())

                   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you iterate over `object_list` in template? Because default list name in `LiseView` is `object_list`: doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

Comment: This is my problem as well. figuring out what the template code should be.

Answer (score 1):

Template code:

```
{% for objects in object_list %}
    {{ objects.title }}
    {{ objects.tag }}
    {{ objects.slug }} 
     ------
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok, looks like there was a misunderstanding :) What I need to do is return a list of shows or objects related to a tag. Not a list of tags. I've been really struggling to figure it out.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I have edited the answer again, so take a look. I am not sure that is that what you want. Hopefully it will help

Comment: No worries. Its cool. I probably should have been more clear. I'm going to try find code in another app that uses Django-taggit and take it from there. Thanks for your help anyway :)